# Instance of an object doesn't show up in Godot

Tags: instance, godot, gdscript

So I basically create 5 instances of a KinematicBody2D. After that I set the position of each instance to a specific spawn point (I mean the first instance goes to the first spawnpoint, the second instance to the second spawnpoint, etc.). The problem is that the instances do not show up. I printed their location and each instance has the same coordinates with the spawnpoint that it should go to.

Here is my code:

```
extends Node2D

const block_scene = preload("res://Block.tscn")
const block_scene = preload("res://Block.tscn")

func _ready():
    var i = 0

    for i in 5:
       var block = block_scene.instance()
       block.position = spawnpoints.get_child(i).position
       print(block.position)
```

Comment: I wonder why it is possible to iterate over an integer in GDScript `for i in 5:`. I've never noticed that before.

Comment: Oh i just noticed that oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to add the `block` instances to the scene tree. If they should be children of your Node2D, you can call the `add_child` method:

```
func _ready():
    for i in range(5):
        var block = block_scene.instance()
        block.position = spawnpoints.get_child(i).position
        add_child(block)
```